# Amazon EC2 Micro Instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am looking for a way to automatically turn off/on a microinstance on session based intervals.  I need to be able to do this to automate when I am paying for the EC2 server. Does anyone know of any ways to do this using PHP or some other backend technology

Comment: What are session based intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always start and stop instances using the AWS command line tools (i.e. make a BASH script to do this) or by using the AWS PHP SDK.  Of course the problem is that you will need some separate server on which you can run a cron or similar to execute your start/stop scripts.

Comment: http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2009/06/howto-get-started-with-amazon-ec2-api-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework 1.x have some classes to work with Amazon EC2 (Zend_Service_Amazon_Ec2).